# Is grouping values with ( value1 || value2) for comparisons valid in JavaScript or TypeScript and if so, why not?

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax, comparison, comparison-operators

I am wondering if grouping values with || while comparing a single variable value is considered valid in the latest JavaScript or TypeScript and if not, does anyone know a reason for this to not become valid syntactic sugar at some point? Or if it is allowed, in what version of JS was this added and what is this type of shortcut comparison called?

```
const exampleVar: 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' = 'a'

// I want to see if example var is 'a' or 'b'
if ( exampleVar === ( 'a' || 'b') ) {
  console.log('Yay!');
} else {
  console.log("Not 'a' or 'b' - Boo!");
}
```

I would expect this to return true if exampleVar is 'a' or 'b'.  It works in console in an evergreen browser so I think my two biggest questions are where can this be safely used and what is this shortcut called so I can check its support in something like CanIUse.

Comment: The syntax is legal, it just doesn't do what you want. Order of operations says to evaluate `'a' || 'b'` first, which just results in `'a'`. So the code is equivalent to `if (exampleVar === 'a')`.

Comment: _"I would expect this to return true if exampleVar is 'a' or 'b'. It works in console in an evergreen browser"_, I think you might want to check that again. If you try with `exampleVar` set to `'b'` you'll get the `else` branch log. (unless when you say "it works" you mean that it doesn't crash?)

Comment: @NickParsons You are correct.  I only tested for the 'a' condition.  After trying again, it failed as you describe. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that doesn't work like you think it does.

`exampleVar === ( 'a' || 'b')` is equivalent to `exampleVar === 'a'`

The `or` operator, return the right hand value if the left hand is falsy.

The closest to what you are looking for is probably :

```
if(['a', 'b'].includes(exempleVar)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthieu!  Great answer with both an explanation of the issue as well as a great solution for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch:

```html
switch(exampleVar) {
case 'a':
case 'b':
  console.log('Yay!');
  break;
case 'c':
  console.log('Yay again!');
  break;
default:
  console.log("Not 'a' or 'b' or 'c' - Boo!");
}
```